# Designing a BJT cascode amplifier for decent gain and bandwidth

Tags: amplifier, circuit-design, bjt, cascode

For my university course assignment I have to design a BJT amplifier using a Cascode stage with the following specifications using LTSpice. Only Vcc=3.3V and ground rails are available as well as a Refernence current \$I_{ref} =50\mu A\$ is allowed for biasing the BJT's using a current mirror.

- Voltage Gain= 80 \$\pm \$5% V/V
- Current Gain= 75 \$\pm\$5% A/A
- Corner Frequency= 40k\$\pm\$5%  Hz
- Power Dissipated= 2\$\pm\$5% mW
- Output swing= atleast 2.64V
- No resistors should be used, only active loads

To start things up, I experimented using a NPN load and driver and even by dc sweeping for minute changes in bias I was not able to get any decent gain.

Next I made a PNP load and NPN driver(pull down circuit), like a CMOS and even this has led to dismal gains even after sweeping through minute changes in bias voltages. I have attached the schematic image below:
[image]

Can someone point me in the right direction as to where I have been going wrong with the design. I think using lower number of transistors are better since biasing them with such a low Vcc is going to be a pain. I have selected four BJT's to use for the cascode since a high gain is necessary as well.

Comment: I'd say you dived in, too quickly, into a schematic. I'd like to see you re-work those specifications for us and develop additional specifications from them. For example, with \$\pm 1.32\:\text{V}\$ at the output and \$A_V\approx 80\$, this implies \$\pm 16.5\:\text{mV}\$ at the input. This is about right for a BJT diff-amp as the first stage. (It's "compatible.") You could write out things like that, plus thoughts about what results. Etc. ... Before jumping in with a schematic. How are you going to achieve that corner frequency, for example? What does the tight dissipation figure say?

Comment: Ok, here are some of the rough calculations I figured out, \$g_{m,npn}=g_{m,pnp}=I_C/V_t= 50\mu/25mV=2mA/V\$ and \$r_{\pi_{pnp}}=156k \$ , \$r_{\pi_{npn}}=190k\$,  \$r_{0_{pnp}}=615k\$ ,\$r_{0_{npn}}=1.19M\Omega\$ .From small signal analysis, The resistance seen upwards from Vout and downwards are in parallel and are equal to \$ g_mr_0r_\pi\$ for the particular npn or pnp bjt. I hope my analysis is right till here. Diff-amps are just getting started in our class hence I am not familiar with them, also I'm not sure whether we can use them here either.

Comment: In the case of corner frequency I am guessing the \$ \omega=\frac{1}{R_{out}C_{bypass}}=40k \$, power dissipation, correct me if I'm wrong shouldn't it be \$V_{cc}*{50\mu A*2}\$ since two rails would need to be supplied to generate \$50\mu A\$?

Comment: @jonk It would be great if you could share your thoughts on this!